# How do make a button find an id name

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to click a button and have the matching id name show. I don't know how to use contains, has, or filter to make this work. Basically, click a button find it's id name. Then, if it's id name matches one in nameList show only that id.

Second question. There has to be a better way to call all the buttonNames than the way I'm doing with variable bn.

```
</head>
<body>
    <div = "list">
        <ul class = "nameList">
            <li id ="Heather">Heather</li>
            <li id ="Cruz">Cruz</li>
            <li id ="Donny">Donny</li>
            <li id ="Jimmy">Jimmy</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div = "buttonList">
        <form class = "buttonNames">
            <input type = "button" id = "Heather" value ="Heather"/>
            <input type = "button" id = "Cruz" value ="Cruz"/>
            <input type = "button" id = "Donny" value ="Donny"/>
            <input type = "button" id = "Jimmy" value ="Jimmy"/>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // JavaScript Document
    google.load("jquery", "1.6.2");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        $('.nameList').hide();

/*      $(nameList).each(function(i) { 
            var i = $(this).text();
            console.log("i = " + i);
        });*/

        //var buttons = $('#Heather, #Cruz, #Donny, #Jimmy');
        var bn = $('.buttonNames').children();
        console.log(bn);

        $(bn).click(function() {
            console.log("You have clicked Button = " + $(this).attr('id'));
            var t = $(this).attr('id');
        });

    });

    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Regarding point 2 - The most efficient would be to change buttonnames from a class to an id the use $('#buttonNames input') to get them all

Comment: This will not work reliably with duplicate IDs (it's illegal HTML).  You must make each id value be unique in your page.  You can change to class names and use the same class name in multiple places if you want.  Or switch to unique IDs everwhere.  If any of these solutions below work, it is luck and they very well may not work in all browsers.  Duplicate ID names do not work reliably in all browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00: Ahh, I mixed up the class and id. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have duplicate IDs in your HTML.  And, you already have the button value that gives you the name you want to refer to the appropriate `LI` tag.  So, I'd suggest that you just get rid of the Id values on the buttons and use `this.value` to give you the name you need.

So, to clean up the HTML to make it legal (no dup IDs), I'd use this HTML:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul id = "nameList">
        <li id="Heather">Heather</li>
        <li id="Cruz">Cruz</li>
        <li id="Donny">Donny</li>
        <li id="Jimmy">Jimmy</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="buttonList">
    <form class="buttonNames">
        <input type="button" value="Heather"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Cruz"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Donny"/><br>
        <input type="button" value="Jimmy"/><br>
    </form>
</div>
```

With this javascript to show only the `LI` tag with the name that matches the button clicked:

```
$("#buttonList input").click(function() {
    $("#nameList li").hide();
    $("#" + this.value).show();
});
```

And, you can see it work in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Vhgrg/

Comment: Apologize for changing my decision. This answer has exactly what I was looking for, and I learned a bit more from it. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: In a CSS selector, `#` refers to an ID.  A period refers to a class.  So, `"#Heather"` is the CSS selector for the object with `id="Heather"`.

Comment: Is it shorthand for nameList li id?

Comment: I just saw your reply after I clicked add comment. Thanks.

Comment: So it's called concatenate. Awesome!

Comment: `"#" + this.value` is just string math.  Add "#" to the string in the variable this.value to get a result like `#Heather`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('input[type=button]', '#buttonList').click(function() {
    alert($('ul.nameList #' + this.id).html());
});
```

edit: make sure you fix your html
`<div = "list">` to `<div id = "list">`
`<div = "buttonList">` to `<div id = "buttonList">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#buttonList input').click(function() {
    $('li').hide();
    $('li#' + this.id).toggle();
});
```

[jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/S2vSy/)

The div that has the form in it does not have the attribute name buttonList specified to be class or id, I assumed id on it. Also as in the comments the ids have to be unique in the page

Comment: All of the answers above helped me understand more than what I didn't know.

Comment: @milkIt: Only one element in the DOM would have a specific string as its id. In the question you have the buttons and the list items have same IDs, which should be avoided

Comment: Understood. I thought it would help for filtering a match, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.buttonNames input').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.nameList #' + id).show();
});
```

Note that the .nameList part is only required due to the invalid duplication of ids.

Also note that in your code you're hiding the whole unordered list, rsther than each item.

So replace `$('.nameList').hide` with `$('.nameList li').hide()`